# SQL : why isn't this query broken

Tags: mysql, sql

I am learning SQL .

The developer has enclosed the `$id` in double quotes. 
So when I put `id=1"` the query breaks.

```
ERROR : "1"") LIMIT 0,1 at line 1
```

However when I put `id=1'` (single quotes) the query doesn't not break.
How is this possible? Single quotes does not have a pair and it should break.

Comment: Try this: `id = ".$id."`

Comment: The ' is treated as part of the string.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic , Can you answer one more question please?.
if ' is treated part of the string, then query should be id=1' but here is no id=1' only id=1, How are the results displayed though there is no id=1'?

Comment: I don't know - I'd have to see the actual query and the database structure (and preferably some sample data as well).

Answer (score 0):

in your sql

do your variables enclosed by single quotes

```
  '$id'
```

or no quotes

```
   $id
```

or like that if your query is with double quotes $query = "select ...." ;

```
  '".$id."'
```

or like that if your query is with single quotes $query = 'select ....' ;

then your variable should be

```
  $id
```